# Why the following comparisons output false?

Tags: javascript, operators

Assuming `Array` was not overwritten, why the following comparisons output false?

```
[] === new Array()
> false

[] === []
> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether using the equality `==` operator or the strict equality `===` operator, if the operands are objects the result will be true only if both operands refer to the *same* object.

Your code creates two distinct arrays, both empty, so intuitively they might seem equal but that is not how the equals operators work.

Similarly something like `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` will be false. Again it is easy to think they should be equal, but the comparison is testing whether the arrays are *the same* array, not whether all of the elements in the array are equal.

On the other hand `x === y` will be true if both `x` and `y` refer to the same array.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two unique Array objects for identity, not content.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are different, as in they are different segments of memory. For example:

```
var a = [],
    b = [];

a === b; // false
typeof a === typeof b; // true
```

Note: the typeof statements are going to return ["object" not "array"](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof). There are much better ways of determining if an object is an array. But this suffices for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator uses the [strict equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6), which says at step 7:

> Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

So if *a* and *b* reference an object, then `a === b` only if *a* and *b* reference the same object (noting that Arrays are Objects).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, when you use `==` and `===` on an object (an array is just an object, `[]` is just syntactic sugar), return `true` only if both operands refer to the exact same object, but not if they refer to 2 different, even identical objects.

For Example:

```
js> var x = []
js> var y = []
js> x == y
false
js> x = y
js> x == y
true
```

Think of it as the difference between two people talking about the same person, versus two people respectively talking about each of two twins.